# Controlling client terminal (linux)

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, irc

In my university I have a server (CLUB Server) but the university local network is closed I mean I can not access the server from outside (from my house for example) but the server have the ability to access another server on the internet so in order to control the server I decided to make my home computer a server and buy a Fix-IP and configure the server to connect to my home server and in that way I will be able to control the University server from my home server

So it's easy to do that for example I can make an IRC server at home and when the university server connect to my home server I will send him command in on the chat space but this is not enough because I want to control the university server terminal so is there any existing application that have the ability to do such a thing or I have to program the control of my IRC chat commands one by one , please post any information you have ?

Comment: key words: [reverse ssh](http://www.google.com/search?q=reverse+ssh)

Comment: thank you sooooooooo much , that's exactly what I'm seeking for :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the Reverse SSH and it's to make the server connect to the client and make an SSH port forwarding from client computer to the server so anyone  will be able to connect to the server just by connecting to the client computer

For more informations -> https://www.howtoforge.com/reverse-ssh-tunneling

Answer (score 0):

you can daisy chain ssh from machine to machine. log onto the the server you can get to from the outside with user@ip once logged in there ssh through the LAN with user@ lan ip for that server.

Comment: Thank you so much but @wumpus-q-wumbley have already gave me the solution :) :)